# Verificar si mi variable string es una variable entera

Tags: c++, array, string, bucles, codeblocks

Una vez que recorres un string como un array, puedo verificar si el string introducido es una variable entera?
Por ejemplo:
Introduces hola y que vuelva a pedir que introduzcas la variable puesto que no es un número entero.

```
 int main()
    {
        string cadena;
        cout << "Introduce cadena" << endl;
        cin >> cadena;
        string::iterator i;
        for (i = cadena.begin(); i < cadena.end(); i++){
            cout << *i << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues tienes que validar que la cadena está compuesta exclusivamente por dígitos:

```
bool ok = std::all_of(cadena.begin(),cadena.end(), [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); });
```

Esta comprobación no verifica que el número entre en un `int`, por ejemplo, es decir, si el usuario introdujese `12345678901234567890`, este algoritmo lo daría por válido pero no podrías meter ese número en un `int`.

Otra comprobación un poco más pesada podría ser convertir el texto a número y el número otra vez a cadena de texto ... si ambas cadenas de texto coinciden ... todo bien

```
int numero = std::stoi(cadena);
std::string test = std::to_string(numero);
bool ok = ( test == cadena );
```

Por supuesto también puede suceder que a ti solo te interese leer el entero como tal, en ese caso puedes comprobar si ha habido algún problema al leer:

```
int numero;
std::cin >> numero;

bool ok = std::cin.good();
```

Por supuesto, en este caso tendrás que limpiar el buffer para eliminar lo que ha dado problemas:

```
if( !ok )
{
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
  std::cin.clear(); // Unicamente limpia el flag de error
}
```